# gorm unsupported data type interface

Tags: go, go-gorm

gorm unsupported data type interface.

How do I save different structures to one field in json (gorm)? Type checking needed, not just serialization in Json.

Example code with error: unsupported data type: models.Fields

```
// table questions (GORM)
type Questions struct {
    ID
    Fields  `json:"fields"`
//  .....
}

type Fields interface{
//  ...
}

// radio ----------
type Radio struct {
    Text string
    Img string
    //  ...
}

func (d Radio) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(d)
}

func (d *Radio) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &d)
}

// Checkbox ----------
type Checkbox struct {
    Text string
    MaxCheckbox   uint16
    //  ...
}

func (d Checkbox) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(d)
}

func (d *Checkbox) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &d)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have already solved this, but you need to use [polymorphism](https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html#Polymorphism-Association).